# To find imported libraries, namespaces and aliases

Tags: php

I Have a huge project which has many aliases and namespaces imported. I want a way to find a way where i can check which **File(.php file)**  is importing which namespaces, aliases. For example:

```
<?php 
    namespace foo; 
    use My\Full\Classname as Another;
    use My\Full\NSname;
    use ArrayObject;
    $obj = new namespace\Another;
    $obj = new Another;
    NSname\subns\func();
    $a = new ArrayObject(array(1));
?>
```

Similarly there a lot of other files how do i find the which classes are dependant on what?
Thank You

Comment: Well i have to get that data from java code. How do i do that?

Comment: Java can call command line tools.

Comment: Well, but it would be better if i had a tool which provides xml, csv o/p which i could parse it easily.

Comment: That would be the tool that you're going to write yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use great [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/) from Nikic. You just have to implement a [node visitor](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/0.9/doc/2_Usage_of_basic_components.markdown#node-traversation).

Comment: could you please provide a tool which has a java API @MartyIX

Comment: I guess there is no PHP parser written in Java. At least not so good as the Nikic's one is.

Comment: @user1232583 That requirement is not part of your question.

Comment: @user1232583: Well, you can write a PHP script that outputs anything you want and then run the PHP script as a command like tool.

Answer (score 0):

Its a nice question !, Have you ever think how auto loading works in Zend frmework and some other ?

All these magics are done by `Reflector`, To know more see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php)

Example 1 : To find a function where it has been defined

```
$temp = new ReflectionFunction('FUNCTION_NAME');

echo $temp->getFileName(); // Path of the file where function defined
```

Example 2 : To find a Class where it has been defined

```
$temp = new ReflectionClass('CLASS_NAME');

echo $temp->getFileName(); // Path of the file where class defined
```